# Getting Index out of range error for List<T> while load testing. It appears to be threading issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, collections, synchronization

In our application, we are receiving a collection (List) as an input parameter to a WCF webmethod, and that input parameter is passed as is, without transferring to any local member, to a StaticClass.StaticMethod. Inside the static method, the first line checks the count of the input parameter List to greater than Zero and the next line I am retrieving the first element (0th index), but it throws “Index out of range” Error while this application is tested using load runner. 
At first glance it appears like a simple race condition, but the load runner access this WCF service via a website and there no way the website can pass empty collection. 
Any thoughts?

```
// Code snippet 
public static List<X> GetCashBalances(List<Y> IPReceivedAtWebMethod)
{
    List<X> list = new List<X>();
    if IPReceivedAtWebMethod== null) return list;
    if IPReceivedAtWebMethod.Count <= 0) return list;
    // The below line throws Index out of range error.
        SomeValue s = AdminHelper.GetSomeValue(IPReceivedAtWebMethod[0].member1);
    // …
}
```

The WCF Service method calling the above method is given below for reference,

```
public class CashService : ICashService
{
public ServiceResponse GenerateCashBalances(RequestToWCFService request)
{
    ServiceResponse response = DataContractFactory.InstanceOfServiceResponse();
    try
    {
        // This is the code calling the method I referred in the question which is throwing Index out of range Error
        response._someList = StaticClass.GetCashBalancesReferredInQuestion(request._someList);
        // I hope this would not do any harm to _someList
        List<CashBalance> list = response._someList.ConvertAll(c => (CashBalance)c);

        // Second call using the same collection however the list is not alterned inside this method too.
        response.someActivity = AdminController.GetActivity(request._someList).ToString("O");
        response.ResponseCode = WcfServiceCodes.OK_RESPONSE;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log error 
    }
    return response;
}
```

Detail about the Request object

```
[DataContract]
public class RequestToWCFService : BaseRequest
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<AccountGroup> _someList { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Is any of this state (particularly the parameter) shared between separate requests?

Comment: Yes, it is passed to two methods from the root method synchronously. As I mentioned in the other answer, there is no parallel threading / async calls I am making.

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a look at how the list is being used by the *calling* method. It'd be pretty easy to say:

```
var balances = GetCashBalances(_someList);
```

... where `_someList` is a static field somewhere that gets consumed by a variety of different methods. If anything removes an element from `_someList`, you're prone to have the problem you're reporting.

See if this helps:

```
var list = _someList.ToList(); // create a local copy.
var balances = GetCashBalances(list);
```

Comment: Yep, the key point here is `and that input parameter is passed as is, without transferring to any local member`.

Comment: I would like to try the same as you suggested. But I am trying to understand the issue. Do I need to create a local copy? Does it imply that the input parameter received at WCF service method is not thread safe Or in other words , is there any possibilities that other threads will change it? I assume that WCF service methods are instance methods and the parameters are preserved.

Comment: @MakR: Typically the parameters passed into a WCF service method are created specifically for the given Request. Can you provide more information about how the web service calls this method? Do you do any parallel processing within this request?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: I do not make any parallel threads or async calls. I have added the calling method details in the question. Can you have a look into it? Thanks.

Comment: @MakR: Can you provide the code for the `RequestToWCFService` class? Specifically with regards to the `_someList` property?

Comment: @MakR: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you change it to an array?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: I couldn't try different settings as I don't have Loadrunner available in my development environment. I thought of using VS2010 Ultimate to simulate the load testing and try debugging this. Please let me know if there is any freeware that I can use for load testing. Anyways thanks a lot for your valuable time. Will keep you posted.

Comment: @MakR: Is your WCF service written in a way that you could create new instances and run the method directly in C#? If so, you could just use a `Parallel.ForEach()` call to invoke the method many times in parallel. Of course, if your error is coming as a result of WCF's binding strategy, this obviously won't uncover your problem. Mostly I was thinking that if you changed the _someList property into an array, the compiler might expose someplace where you didn't realize you were calling `Remove` on it.